# Правильность написания в проводнике, как попасть на второй SMB?

Tags: windows, samba, порт, smb

5 раз переписываю))
Добрый день!
У меня подключено два ubuntu-компа к роутеру zyxel, ip статический, на каждом компе установлен свой smb, в роутере для внешнего подключения для первого компа проброшены порты 445, 139,  для второго перенаправил 40445 на 445, и 40139 на 139 второго компа. При внешнем подключении в windows проводнике указываю \\сервер и попадаю на самбу первого компа.
Вопрос: как в проводнике windows указать порт второго компа?

Comment: `smb://host:port`?

Comment: в проводнике так не работает

Comment: "из..вернуться" и ремапить порты в удаленном сегменте на любой другой комп , а уже в этом сегменте обращаться к адресу компа (куда сделан ремап). При этом сам же комп может выступить сервером (если на него сделан ремап). Но в тоже время следует освободить данные порты (т.е. остановить соответствующие сервисы). Изврат конечно же. Хотя не прокатит... Там вроде бы TCP-сеанс устанавливается c использованием IP сервера.

Comment: Лучше поднять VPN-сервер на любом из Ubuntu узлов (и открыть его наружу). Либо воспользоваться SSH-,socks-прокси. Есть ещё вариант - поднять DFS - соответственно подключаться только к одному серверу, в то время как его "шара" будет ссылаться на соседний сервер.

Comment: А чем не устроил вебдав?